# Confused about X86 segmentation

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, memory-segmentation

I am writing a boot sector to load my 16-bit real mode DOS clone, and I'm stuck on something which might be completely obvious, but I've spent hours of time trying to understand why it won't work.

Basically, I'm trying to set `DS`, `CS`, `SS` to zero, but keep `ES` set directly past 7C00 to load the system.

But when running my code through a debugger, it says that nothing was ever read into memory, i.e.: root, FATs, etc (???)

Basically, I'm trying to compare `DS:SI` (0000:7C00+FILE) TO `ES:DI` (07E0:0000), but to no avail. I heard someone tell me that it actually checks `DS:SI` with `DS:DI` and so I tried it, but that didn't work either.
Shouldn't 07E0:0000 be directly after 0000:7C00? Does `cmpsb` require `ES` & `DS` to be the same?

I've looked in the Intel manuals, but it says that `cmpsb` compares `DS:SI` to `ES:DI`, but I don't think I'm misunderstanding too much. 07E0:0000 is 0x7E00, no?

Anyway, thanks for any help. I appreciate it.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if I zero `ES` and put the load address into `BX`, everything works. But when it's flipped, `ES=07E0`, `BX=0`, nothing works or is even read. No idea why, since `ES:BX` should be the same thing regardless of which route you take.

My code:

```
ORG 7C00H
    USE16

BPBBEG:
    JMP  SHORT BPBPEND
    NOP

        DB "PEDOS1.0"
BYTSPERSEC: DW 512      ; total bytes per sector on this volume
SECPERCLUS: DB 1        ; total sectors per cluster on this volume
RSVDSECCNT: DW 1        ; unused
NUMFATS:    DB 2        ; total FATs on this volume
ROOTENTCNT: DW 224      ; total entries in the Root Directory
        DW 80 * 36
        DB 240
FATSZ16:    DW 9        ; total sectors per FAT on this volume
SECPERTRK:  DW 18       ; total sectors per track on this idks
NUMHEADS:   DW 2        ; total heads per cyliner on this idks
        DD 0
        DD 0
        DB 0
        DB 0
        DB 41
        DD 0
        DB "           "
        DB "FAT12   "
;
; PEDOS MEMORY MAP
;
;   -  --  ROM / VIDEO  -- A000:0
;   -   -----------------
;   -  --  BIOS DATA    -- 8000:0
;   -   -----------------
;   -  --  FREE         -- ????:?
;   -   -----------------
;   -  --  BOOT / FREE  -- 0000:7C00
;   -   -----------------
;   -  --  FREE         -- ????:?
;   -   -----------------
;   -  --  DRIVERS      -- ????:?
;   -   -----------------
;   -  --  SYSTEM       -- 0050:0
;   -   -----------------
;   -  --  BIOS BATA    -- 0000:400
;   -   -----------------
;   -  --  IVT          -- 0000:0
;

;
; INITIALIZE SEGMENT REGISTERS
;
BPBPEND:
    XOR  AX, AX
    MOV  DS, AX
    CLI
    PUSH DS
    POP  SS
    MOV  SP, 7C00H
    PUSH DS
    PUSH CHKDSK
    STI
    RETF    ; SET CS TO KNOWN VALUE
;
; LOAD ROOT DIRECTORY AND CHECK FOR
; SYSTEM FILE
;
CHKDSK:
    MOV  AX, WORD BUFFER
    SHR  AX, 4
    MOV  ES, AX ; ES = 07E0
    XOR  AX, AX
    MOV  AX, WORD [FATSZ16]
    MUL  WORD [NUMFATS]
    ADD  AL, BYTE [RSVDSECCNT]
    ;mov  bx, 0x7e00
    MOV  DI, 1
    CALL READSEC


;   mov  ah, 14
;   mov  al, '/'
;   int  16
;   jmp  $

    LEA  SI, [FILE] ; ADDRESS OF FILENAME
    MOV  DI, 0
    MOV  CX, 11     ; 11 BYTES PER FAT FILENAME
    CLD
    REPZ CMPSB
    JZ   LOADFILE
    JMP  ERROR

; DOSBIOS.SYS CONFIRMED: LOAD THE
; FILE INTO MEMORY.

LOADFILE:
    mov  ah, 14
    mov  al, '.'
    int  16
    jmp  $

    MOV  AX, 32
    MOV  BX, WORD [ROOTENTCNT]  ; TOTAL FATS ON DISK
    MUL  BX
    MOV  BX, WORD [BYTSPERSEC]  ; FAT SIZE IN SECTORS
    DIV  BX
    ;
    ; AX = SIZE OF ROOT DIRECTORY
    ;   IN SECTORS
    ;
    ADD  AX, BP ; SIZE + LOCATION = DATA REGION
    POP  BX
    PUSH BX
    MOV  DI, 1  ; DOS SIZE IS HARD CODED FOR NOW - MAY
    CALL READSEC    ; CHANGE IN THE FUTURE
RUNDOS:
    POP  BX
    PUSH 0
    PUSH BX
    RETF
;
; READ THE SPECIFIED SECTORS INTO MEMORY
; AT LOGICAL ES:BX      
;
; IN:   DX:AX   = HEAD, TRACK, SECTOR NUMBER
;   DI  = SECTOR COUNT
;
READSEC:
    PUSHA
    DIV  WORD [SECPERTRK]
    ;
    ; AX = LBA / SECPERTRACK
    ; DX = LBA % SECPERTRACK
    ;
    MOV  CX, DX
    INC  CX     ; CX = LBA 1
    XOR  DX, DX
    DIV  WORD [NUMHEADS]
    ;
    ; AX = (LBA / SECPERTRACK) / CYLHEADCNT = CYLINDER
    ; DX = (LBA / SECPERTRACK) % CYLHEADCNT = HEAD
    ;
    MOV  CH, AL
    SHL  AH, 6
    OR   CL, AH
    MOV  DH, DL
    MOV  DL, 0
    ;
    ; DH = HEAD HUMBER
    ; DL = DRIVE
    ;
    MOV  AH, 2
    MOV  AL, 1
    INT  19
    JNC  NEXTSEC    ; IN CASE OF ERRORS, FOLLOW
ERROR:
    LEA  SI, [ERRMSG]   ; SOMETHING WENT WRONG, SO THROW AN ERROR
;
; WRITE SPECIFIED STRING TO VIDEO
; MEMORY
;
; DS:SI = ADDRESS OF STRING
;
PRINT:
    LODSB
    OR   AL, 0
    JZ   HALT
    MOV  AH, 14
    MOV  BX, 7
    INT  16
    JMP  PRINT
HALT:
    MOV AX, 0
    INT 22
    INT 25
;
; CONTINUE 'READSEC'
;
NEXTSEC:
    POPA
    DEC  DI
    JZ   RETURN ; SKIP PRINT SUBROUTINE
    ADD  BX, WORD [BYTSPERSEC]
    ADD  AX, 1
    ADC  DX, 0
    JMP  READSEC
RETURN:
    RET
;
; KEEP DATA BELOW CODE, UNTIL SECTOR
; MARKER
;
ERRMSG: DB 10, "Disk Error or DOSBIOS.SYS is missing.", 13
    DB 10, "Press any key to restart.", 13, 10, 10, 0
FILE:   DB "DOSBIOS SYS"

    TIMES (512 - 2) - ($ - $$) DB 0

MARKER: DW 0AA55H
BUFFER:
;
; THE SYSTEM IS LOADED DIRECTLY AFTER
; BOOTSTRAP
;
```

Comment: `Does Cmpsb require ES & DS to be the same?` no

Comment: `07E0:0 is 0x7E00,no?` it is

Comment: `Shouldn't 07E0:0 be directly after 0000:7c00?` with 512 bytes beeing "directly after" yes.

Comment: you shouldnt push anything before the stack is set up (first "push ds" after "BPBPEND")

Comment: @Tommylee2k: Why not?  There definitely *is* a valid stack somewhere, not overlapping with the 512 bytes of your code or anything that the BIOS considers valuable.  (Otherwise that would be a massively buggy BIOS).  Otherwise `int` couldn't work, and interrupts are enabled when jumping to the boot sector.

Comment: @Michael Petch bochs command-line debugger

Comment: Also, @Michael Petch, I'm using VirtualBox to test

Comment: You did `MOV  ES, AX ; ES = 07E0`
    `XOR  AX, AX` . Did you mean that to be `MOV  ES, AX ; ES = 07E0`
    `XOR  BX, BX`

Comment: No. I tried `XOR BX, BX` and nothing worked. I believe I did that to reset the high byte of AX so that the disk operation worked.Using bochs debugger and doing `xp /512h 0x7e00` shows nothing at all.does  does ES=07E0,BX=0 mean 0x7e00? My disk reading works, because of I use only offsets, everything works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Check your sizes!

On the one hand you define:

> ```
> RSVDSECCNT: DW 1        ; unused
> NUMFATS:    DB 2        ; total FATs on this volume
> ROOTENTCNT: DW 224      ; total entries in the Root Directory
> ```

On the other hand you calculate:

> ```
> MOV  AX, WORD [FATSZ16]
> MUL  WORD [NUMFATS]
> ADD  AL, BYTE [RSVDSECCNT]
> ```

1. The assembler will encode what you've asked and multiply `AX` with the **word** NUMFATS which involves using a garbage high byte (in this case the value 224)!
2. You get away with the equally wrong addition of RSVDSECCNT because the numbers involved are so small - at least if the first issue is corrected! But since that one is defined as word you really should have written `add ax, [RSVDSECCNT]`.

Solution:

```
MOVZX AX, BYTE [NUMFATS]
MUL   AX, WORD [FATSZ16]
ADD   AX, WORD [RSVDSECCNT]
```

### The pointer goes in `ES:BX`

> ```
> CHKDSK:
>     MOV  AX, WORD BUFFER
>     SHR  AX, 4
>     MOV  ES, AX ; ES = 07E0
>     XOR  AX, AX
> ```

Change that `XOR AX, AX` to `XOR BX, BX`